# Getting more information from CvHoughCircles

Tags: .net, opencv, geometry, hough-transform

I am using the [HoughCircles](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles) function of OpenCV.

Is there any way I can get more information about the results besides an ordered list of circle center and radius?

I'd like to get the score of each circle, and perhaps the hough space matrix itself

I am using the openCvdotnet C# wrapper, but I am not adverse to modifying the wrapper.

I tried implementing my own hough gradient circle transform, but the results are not as robust as the native openCV function.

Comment: Look carefully at the docs. If it ain't there, you're gonna have to do it yourself. This question is better suited to [http://answers.opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple, no there isn't. I've needed something like this in the past and decided it was simpler to implement my own (based on one of the freely available matlab examples) than to modify the opencv code.